# R code for repeating value into column

Tags: r

I am basically new to using R software.

I have a list of repeating codes (numeric/ categorical) from an excel file. I need to add another column values (even at random) to which every same code will get the same value.

```
Codes Value
 1  122
 1  122
 2  155
 2  155
 2  155
 4  101
 4  101
 5  251
 5  251
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `match`:

```
n <- length(code0 <- unique(code))
value <- sample(4 * n, n)[match(code, code0)]
```

or `factor`:

```
n <- length(unique(code))
value <- sample(4 * n, n)[factor(code)]
```

The random integers generated are between 1 and `4 * n`. The number `4` is arbitrary; you can also put `100`.

---

**Example**

```
set.seed(0); code <- rep(1:5, sample(5))

code
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5

n <- length(code0 <- unique(code))
sample(4 * n, n)[match(code, code0)]

# [1]  5  5  5  5  5 18 18 19 19 19 19 12 12 12 11
```

---

**Comment**

The above gives **the most general treatment**, assuming that `code` is not readily sorted or taking consecutive values.

If `code` is sorted (no matter what value it takes), we can also use `rle`:

```
if (!is.unsorted(code)) {
  n <- length(k <- rle(code)$lengths)
  value <- rep.int(sample(4 * n, n), k)
  }
```

If `code` takes consecutive values `1, 2, ..., n` (but not necessarily sorted), we can skip `match` or `factor` and do:

```
n <- max(code)
value <- sample(4 * n, n)[code]
```

---

**Further notice**: If `code` is not numerical but categorical, `match` and `factor` method will still work.

Comment: Will it work when my code variable is character? And When I have introduced another column B, like when my data frame consists of not only those two columns above?

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do is the following, it is perhaps more intuitive to a beginner:

```
data <- data.frame('a' = c(122,122,155,155,155,101,101,251,251))

duplicates <- unique(data)
duplicates[, 'b'] <- rnorm(nrow(duplicates))

data <- merge(data, duplicates, by='a')
```